# testscript execution behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome while manipulating a <select> element

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm facing a weird problem, which I will try to describe in the next rows.
Thank you in advance for your help!

**The problem is that in my case, Testcafe behaves differently when running the same test script on different browsers.**
*testcafe*: 0.23.1
*firefox*: 63.0.1
*chrome*: 70.0.3538.102
*typescript*: 3.1.6

Typescript code from the executed test script:

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
fixture `stackoverflow`
.page `https://www.verivox.de/internet-vergleich/internetundtelefon/?Prefix=030&speed=16000#/offer?i=eyJmaWx0ZXIiOltudWxsLDE2MDAwLDEsbnVsbCwiMDMwIiwxLDEsMSxudWxsLDEsMSxudWxsLC0xLG51bGwsbnVsbCwicHJpY2UtYXNjIiwyLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCw2XSwiZGlhbG9nIjpbbnVsbF0sIm9mZmVyQ3JpdGVyaWEiOlsiNjM0ODkyIiwiMTg0ODYiLG51bGwsIjI0IiwzLDIsIjUwMDAwIiwiMTAwMDAiLG51bGwsbnVsbCwxLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLCIyIiwxLG51bGwsIjAzMCIsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLDEsNixudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbF19`;
test('1', async () => {

const acceptCookiesButton = Selector('span.gdpr-vx-consent-bar-button');
const showAvailabilityCheckButton = Selector(Selector('a').withAttribute('class', /offer-page-cta/));
const contactDataEMailTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_ContactData_EMail');
const confirmationEmailTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_ContactData_EMailConfirmation');
const genderSelect = Selector('select[name="PersonalData.AddressData.ConnectionAddress.Gender"]');
const genderSelectOptionGet = genderSelect.find('option');
const genderSelectOption = Selector(genderSelectOptionGet);
const firstNameTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_AddressData_ConnectionAddress_FirstName');
const nameTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_AddressData_ConnectionAddress_Name');
const zipTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_AddressData_ConnectionAddress_Zip');
const cityTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_AddressData_ConnectionAddress_City');
const buildingTypeRadioInput = Selector('#Einfamilienhaus');
const bankInformationTypeRadioInput = Selector('#PersonalData_BankData_BankInformationType_KnrBlz');
const bankCodeTextInput = Selector('#PersonalData_BankData_BankCode');

await t
    .click(acceptCookiesButton)
    .click(showAvailabilityCheckButton)
    .wait(2000)
    .typeText(contactDataEMailTextInput, 'asd@asd.asd')
    .typeText(confirmationEmailTextInput, 'asd@asd.asd')
    .click(genderSelect)
    .click(genderSelectOption.withText('Herr'))
    .typeText(firstNameTextInput, 'Test')
    .typeText(nameTextInput, 'Test')
    .typeText(zipTextInput, '67112')
    .click(cityTextInput)
    .expect(cityTextInput.value).eql('Mutterstadt')
    .click(buildingTypeRadioInput)
    .click(bankInformationTypeRadioInput)
    .wait(2000)
    .expect(bankCodeTextInput.exists).ok('field not displayed');

});
```

I am using VisualStudio Code to write my code, and I'm executing the test in Firefox browser, with the option -e:

> testcafe firefox .\stackoverflow.ts -e

**Question 1:**
I'm executing the exactly same test script with
`Firefox`: everything works, test passes
`Chrome`: test fails and I receive the below error:

```
1) The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.

  Browser: Chrome 70.0.3538 / Windows 10.0.0

     38 |        .click(showAvailabilityCheckButton)
     39 |        .wait(2000)
     40 |        .typeText(contactDataEMailTextInput, 'asd@asd.asd')
     41 |        .typeText(confirmationEmailTextInput, 'asd@asd.asd')
     42 |        .click(genderSelect)
   > 43 |        .click(genderSelectOption.withText('Herr'))
     44 |        .typeText(firstNameTextInput, 'Test')
     45 |        .typeText(nameTextInput, 'Test')
     46 |        .typeText(zipTextInput, '67112')
     47 |        .click(cityTextInput)
     48 |        .expect(cityTextInput.value).eql('Mutterstadt')

     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\gco\gco-e2e-baseline\src\playground\e2etests\stackoverflow.ts:43:10)
```

In order to avoid this error, I'm doing the next workaround:

> .click(genderSelect).click(genderSelect)

and now, running the test script on Chrome browser also returns a pass result. 
What is wrong in my code, and why do I encounter this difference in behavior?

**Question 2:**
Considering I'm using the above workaround (the 2 clicks), executing the test script under Chrome, gets me to the next problem:

```
 Running tests in:
- Chrome 70.0.3538 / Windows 10.0.0
stackoverflow
√ 1
1 passed (34s)
```

**Test is passing, even tho not all the code lines are executed...**, because looking at the radio box I'm trying to click and having the browser visible,

> .click(buildingTypeRadioInput)

the radio box is clearly not clicked, but still the test passes?! 
There are some other code lines after this line that are not executed
As a temporary solution, again I'm doing this:

> .click(buildingTypeRadioInput).click(buildingTypeRadioInput)

just to make sure that the test does what I want him to do.
What is wrong in my code, and why do I encounter this issue, with returning a pass instead of a fail?

Comment: first workaround to eliminate the differences between browsers:
1. I am maximizing the browser window;
2. instead of selecting an effective option (the normal and logical way) from the combo, I will press the Down Key, which will select the first option...
3. now, without doing anything else, the radioBox is also clicked :)

Comment: does the post need more details? is it reproducible for someone else except me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the first issue. I think this unexpected behavior is somehow connected with the information popup. You mentioned that you are maximizing the browser window and it helps. As I see, this leads to changes in the render, so the cause of the issue lies here. I think it is a bug so I've created a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3150) in the TestCafe repository. For now, I recommend using the workaround with the maximizing.

As for the second question, I've found that the markup of radio input is complex (inputs are invisible, opacity equals  0), so I recommend you modify your selector in the following manner:

`const buildingTypeRadioInput = Selector('label[for="Einfamilienhaus"]');`

Comment: 10Q @alex. Will try this out.

Comment: yes, the selection of the radiobox is much faster now. It's doing it like instant, not waiting anymore after the timeout

Comment: @Eugen, does the issue persist? I wanted to fix it in the context of the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3150 ticket. However, it looks like the original web site changed so I cannot reproduce it anymore. If the issue still occurs, could you please provide me with details at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3150 ?

Comment: I haven't encountered the problem again. As you noticed, the site changed and I can't find another reproducible scenario for the moment. 10x for asking.

Comment: I'll close the issue on GitHub if you don't mind. Please feel free to create a new one if you are able to reproduce it again.